Does disconnecting the control ceiling fan switch in the fan housing cut the power to the fan? The fan has froze
Fan has frozen because of roof leak and just want to remove the adjusting switch wiring that runs the fan so i can run the light by it self until i replace the whole unit No! you have a switch for the light (in the ceiling fan unit) and you have a switch that control the speed of the fan in the unit! if you remove that switch that control the speed will it cut power to the fan

It appears you are asking how to cut power to a ceiling fan.  If you have a more specific question then please add details, model numbers, and photos.

If the lights work, just use them and ignore the fan switch until you replace the fan. What, exactly, is your question here? Please take the [tour] and look at "how to ask a good question" in the [help], then [edit] your question to provide more detail on exactly what it is you're trying to do and what you're asking about.

I would suspect the whole fan/light to be damaged till checked out.  The lights might still work, but that is not enough to be safe/working correctly.

Turning off the appropriate circuit breaker cuts the power to the fan.  Until that is done, assume all wires are live.

No! you have a switch for the light (in the ceiling fan unit) and you have a switch that control the speed of the fan in the unit! if you remove that switch that control the speed will it cut power to the fan

@LavonThurston NEC 110.3(B) is one of the most basic rules about electrical equipment.  If there are instructions provided by the manufacturer for removing a switch from this fan, then please attach those instructions to help illustrate the idea.
